# Google spreadsheet importHTML Could not fetch URL

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, stock

Can someone confirm it for me?

I'm helping someone with the importHTML problem on Google spreadsheet. I'm not familiar with importHTML but I thought it should work.

```
=importhtml("http://www.stockq.org/","table",1)
```

I don't care which table I'm importing so long as it imports something. It's giving out error message `Error: Could not fetch url: http://www.stockq.org/`. But the web site is accessible in my browser. That's really bizarre.

Comment: As of Jun 26th, 2020 `IMPORTHTML` is working for `http://www.stockq.org/`

Answer (score 1):

My Google Spreadsheet can't cope with the Chinese characters but numbers recognisable by me on the web page are happily imported, as least for the middle table of the three, with:

```
=importhtml("http://www.stockq.org/","table",A12)
```

This is much what was I think mentioned by @DigitalSeraphim way back in September. To quote from an answer that was deleted (as not an answer?):

> So, I have been building a page to help me keep up with mod updates for my minecraft server, using importxml heavily. I have found that I get the same error for some sites that load absolutely fine in the browser. Looking into it further, I found that the sites are reporting a 404 error, but actually returning the data requested. According to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/110651/how-to-show-a-node-but-return-http-404-response, this is used to remove pages from search engines, as I had assumed. I don't think there is any way around this without some hackery... namely, setting up a "proxy" server that would "fix" the status.
>
> However, it appears that the example you gave is now working, so maybe give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Use `IMPORTXML` with XPaths.

---

I encountered similar problem where I tried to switch between `http` and `https`. The work around worked occasionally but the result is not consistent (either way failed a lot).

Later I noticed there is another API named `IMPORTXML` (XML, not HTML here). With this one you can actually query the content from the same URL and apply XPath instead.

Therefore I would suggest to switch to use `IMPORTXML`. For example, the following formula

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.stockq.org/index/IBOV.php", "//table[@class='indexpagetable']")
```

will give you all the tables that have class `indexpagetable` from the page of the given URL.

Note the XPath is slightly different in the spreadsheet, you can refer to the documents for more specifics.