# Automatically update data values, in constant locations, from source cells in spreadsheet

Tags: html, google-sheets, google-docs

I've copied to a google document the html code that comprises my webpage. But I need to frequently update the values (non-code text and data; the stuff people actually see on my website) within the code. All the text and data (sports statistics) I display on the site come from a spreadsheet that updates regularly.

Is there a way to link the data spaces in my copied html document with their source cells in my spreadsheet? Or do I just have to enter them manually as I've been doing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the function [IMPORTDATA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335)

Please not that the better one to use would be [IMPORTHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en) but this [does not currently work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283037/google-spreadsheet-importhtml-could-not-fetch-url?noredirect=1#comment39430409_25283037) in new spreadsheets.